# Quartz.net Jobs on Load balancer

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, load-balancing, quartz.net

I have a quartz.net scheduler implementation (and jobs). The scheduler is inside my website/application itself and runs jobs async at specified time intervals.

It is all very well on local and testing . As soon as i move this code to live (which has multiple load balancers running instances of my website), the jobs start firing as many times as there are load balancers.

How do i handle this? How do i make sure that there is just one scheduler that runs jobs across all my load balancers.

Alternatively is there a way for me to find out when was the previous job fired (on any of the load balancers!)

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to put a scheduler in a web application? I would imagine batch jobs could be offloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a database as your job store, point all your schedulers at the same database and set them up as clustered, then your jobs will be shared across the servers and you won't have them firing multiple times.

Alternatively you could also move your scheduler out into it's own windows service and then share it across your web servers.